# Empty cssrulesets on styled components production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have built a React design library on my site using styled components. I have it built and published to npm. I use this design lib on my other app which also has an instance of styled components running. This then makes my app inject 2 style tags at the head of my app. One for my design library and one for the components I create on my app. When I dev locally all styles work and I can see cssrules being applied to both styles.

But when I build my app for production I can only see cssrules being applied for my app's styles and not for my design library.

The stylesheet exists in the dom but it's empty for some reason.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

This is a console log of the stylesheet in production

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, I had styled-components as a dev dependency on my design package and was only installing production packages with `npm install --production` on my production environment. So I fixed this by setting styled-components as a dependency instead of a dev dependency